# How to check for Boolean without using For Loop?

Tags: python

I have this running well, however am unable to avoid the loop, how can I get an only `True` if present or `False` if not present without having to loop through the list using a for loop?

```
my_list = [[1, 2], [4, 6], [8, 3]]
combined = [3, 8]
for value in my_list:
    print(value)
    if set(combined) == set(value):
        print("present")
    else:
        print("absent")
```

Comment: Your code will output `absent` twice and `present` once. Is that intentional?

Comment: That is what am trying to avoid, I just want to know if present and if not present once, let me check out the answers.

Comment: If that's only what you're trying to solve, then you should check the [`for/else` construct](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). You basically need to add a `break` in the `if` and unindent the `else`. Then, the answers below still simplify the loop in a nice way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the multiple `absent` printing, you can use a [`for/else` construct](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
for value in my_list:
    if set(combined) == set(value):
        print("present")
        break
else:
    print("absent")
```

But if you're looking to optimize/reduce the loop, you can *"hide"* the loop inside an [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) call:

```
any(set(combined) == set(value) for value in my_list)
```

Or alternatively use a list comprehension to convert all sub-lists to sets:

```
set(combined) in [set(sublist) for sublist in my_list]
```

But as you can see, some sort of looping is necessary. I believe that by removing the loop you meant to reduce its code size.

Comment: If anything, use a generator for the second option. That way you will have the short-circuiting and not waste memory for a spurious list.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Indeed that would be better. I will leave it like that as your answer is cleaner in that aspect using the `map` (got my upvote)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this rather concisely, getting the short-circuiting of `any` and the brevity of `map` all while avoiding ugly `lambda` or barely readable conditional expressions:

```
if set(combined) in map(set, my_list):
    print("present")
else:
    print("absent")
```

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer a generator with `next`:

```
next(("present" for value in my_list if set(value) == set(combined)), 'absent')
```

Or with `any`:

```
['absent', 'present'][any(set(combined) == set(value) for value in my_list)]
```

Or even better with `map` and `in`:

```
['absent', 'present'][set(combined) in map(set, my_list)]
```

All output:

```
present
```

Answer (score 2):

Using built-in function `any` and class `map`,

```py
def is_inside(item, items):
    return any(map(lambda x:set(x)==set(combined), my_list))

my_list = [[1, 2], [4, 6], [8, 3]]
combined = [3, 8]

if is_inside(combined, my_list):
    print("present")
else:
    print("absent")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursion:

```
def is_present(seq, elem, n=None):
    if n is None:
       n = len(seq) - 1
    if n == -1:
       return False
    if set(seq[n]) == set(elem):
       return True
    return is_present(seq, elem, n-1)
```

```
if is_present(my_list, combined):
    print("Present")
else:
    print("Not present")
```

There is also a problem with your existing code. You shouldn't have an `else` inside the loop body because if the very first element in `my_list` is not equal to `combined`, it will print `Not present` even though it may be present in the list later. And it will do this for every element that is not equal to it. This can be fixed with a  `for`-`else` statement:

```
my_list = [[1, 2], [4, 6], [8, 3]]
combined = [3, 8]
for value in my_list:
    print(value)
    if set(combined) == set(value):
        print("present")
        break
else:
  print("absent")
```

Or you can just wrap it in a function:

```
def is_present():
    my_list = [[1, 2], [4, 6], [8, 3]]
    combined = [3, 8]
    for value in my_list:
        print(value)
        if set(combined) == set(value):
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

From your problem statement I am able to understand is that you just want to find out that the list in combined inside the 2D list i.e my_list

**Solution**- you could directly use the the following block of code to get your result;

`print("present") if set(combined) == set(value) else print("absent")`

Comment: What is `value` here? Is it the loop variable? And this code should be inside the loop? In that case this is exactly the same as the original code...